# Как можно назвать семью отшельников?

Tags: лексика, синонимы

В тексте именую людей, которые живут в одиноко стоящей хижине (в лесу, в горах, в степи) - отшельниками. Но они не монахи и не лесники. Правильно ли это? Каким синонимом можно заменить...?

Answer (score 2):

Нормально. Отшельник - не обязательно монах.
Лыковы. Отшельники. И жили семьёй.

[Лыковы (отшельники) | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_(%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8))

Да, есть некоторая сложность восприятия, связанная с традицией называть так именно монахов, но лучше слова я не подберу.

Что касается синонимов, то они хуже, поскольку нагружены разными дополнительными значениями.

Comment: Действительно, согласно Википедии, понятие "семья отшельников" существует. Интересно. Ставлю плюс за ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Такие поселения, что вы описали часто называли "Почи́нок" (от слова "почин"), так как впоследствии из подобного поселения могли вырасти деревни, почин ведь первопоселенцами положен. Топоним "Почи́нок" до сих пор часто встречается на карте России, особенно в Вологодской области, жителей Починка называют **починцы**, возможно это слово вам подойдёт.

Comment: Нет, не то... В данном контексте я описываю страны Латинской Америки (но вообще, люди , живущие одинокой хижиной в пустыне, мне встречались и в Судане). Вряд ли к ним кто-то присоединится. "Починок" - это сугубо российское...

Answer (score 0):

> Отшельник — человек, живущий в уединении, избегающий общества людей.

Следовательно, вы пишете правильно.

Синонимы:

1. Анахор**е**т — *(устар.)* Отшельник; тот, кто живёт в уединении, избегая людей.
2. Монах — мужчина, ведущий уединенный, аскетический образ жизни.
3. Затворник —  человек, ведущий уединенный образ жизни.
4. Пустынник, или пустынножитель *(устар.)*, — тот, кто живет уединенно, вдали от людей.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти люди (встречал неоднократно в разных странах) обычно живут большой , иногда многодетной семьей. Но хижина такой семьи стоит особняком и до ближайшего поселения - десятки километров.

Comment: @Виктор в таком случае вы можете выбрать синонимы, в толковании которых нет указания на пол, то есть *анахор**е**ты, затворники, пустынники*.

Comment: Может, "хуторяне" подойдёт?

Comment: @Alex_ander в хуторах обычно *усадьбы* владельцев должны быть, а тут про аскетизм говорится

Comment: @Alex_ander Хутор из одной хижины не бывает: хотя бы 5 должно быть. А "семья отшельников" - это, наверное абсурд...

Comment: @Виктор Хутор по среднерусским понятиям - именно что одна, отдельно стоящая "хижина"  (домохозяйство). Вот на Украине, Кубани - да, это небольшой поселок. ("Вечера на Хуторе близ Диканьки" - Гоголь). Хотя тоже не везде так. Там, где русское влияние сильнее - все равно одна "хижина" ("Хуторок в степи" - Катаев).

Comment: @Бегемот "Хутора" я тоже встречал: в Боливии, в горах. От 3 до 10 глиняных хижин, а вокруг пустыня на десятки, и даже сотни километров. Но когда хижина одна... как-то не вяжется с понятием "хутор". Как в поговорке: лучший парень на деревне, а в деревне один дом. Но это уже народный юмор.